# Not able to trigger any function after the web auth redirection completed

Tags: ios, swift, url, authorization

I have a button to authorize a user via the browser. And it has a target function as below.

```
@objc func handleWebAuth() {
    AuthManager.shared.getRequestToken() { result, error in
        if result {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.open(AuthManager.Endpoints.webAuth.url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        } else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

There is nothing wrong to open URL in safari as required

- info.plist has;

[image]

Related URL is `https://www.themoviedb.org/authenticate/\(Auth.requestToken)?redirect_to=login-app:authenticate` which redirects to the app.

After redirection is completed, I would like to create sessionID after user logged in via browser, but the below function which is in SceneDelegate does not work.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
    if components?.scheme == "login-app" && components?.path == "authenticate" {
        AuthManager.shared.createSessionId { (result, error) in
            print(result)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to determine if your function is even being called?

Comment: Of course, the function is not called.